# AVD not working correctly in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I have been developing android apps in eclipse and since moving to android studio, i can't load apps to my already existing AVDs it just tries to create a new one. which is always damaged. after, it keep saying my already existing AVD is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im guessing you already had android-sdk with eclipse, android studio creates it's own. set your studio's sdk to the old one, click your project's settings and choose it from the SDK pane.
Also if that fails you can try to create an AVD from the studio AVD manager not from eclipse. that worked for me.