# Cannot create new AVD Device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

i am using android studio version 0.8.2,
i am trying to create an avd, but the OK button cannot be pressed.

didn't find anything relevant to my version online.

Comment: I would've thought you'd get a better reception (or a previously answered question) on the Android Enthusiasts forum.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup everything properly, if the cpu is not able to choose, you need to install the corresponding package in SDK manager

check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24980033/2777381

Answer (score 1):

Do you install **gradle**? Make sure your Android Studio installs the **gradle** when you first start and create a project.
Also make sure `File -> Project Structure -> SDKs` list your Android SDK and you have given the right PATH there.
Also check:

- [I can't see AVD manager window in android studio 0.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946881/i-cant-see-avd-manager-window-in-android-studio-0-4-0)
- [AVD not working correctly in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254959/avd-not-working-correctly-in-android-studio)